# Hide table When there are no elements in its body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have ajax link in my table which will delete elements on click. I want to make sure that when all the elements are deleted the table should hide itself. I cannot add any event on the ajax call. Meaning to say I cannot edit or change any ajax success or anyother parameter or function. I want something that will keep checking the table on its own and when there is no element in the table body hide the table and when an entry is made it will display its self

Comment: You could still use global ajax event callback function to override any ajax request

Comment: Can you give me example or point me to one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setInterval()` to repeatedly call a function to do the check for you. Then use the variation of [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) that takes a boolean:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $table = $('.tablesorter');
    $table.toggle($table.find('tbody').children().length > 0);
}, 500);
```

That will check roughly twice every second (once every 500 milliseconds), you can change the second argument to increase or decrease the frequency of the check.

Comment: Not Working Am I Doing Something Wrong `<table class="tablesorter table-bordered table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th class="filter-false">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
var $table = $('tablesorter');
$table.toggle($table.find('tbody').children().length > 0);
}, 500);
</script>`

Comment: @CJ You're missing the `.` in the selector to indicate that it's a class, not a tag name. Should be `var $table - $('.tablesorter');`. I'll update my answer now there's HTML to work with (could you edit that into the question, please?)

Comment: Using setInterval to check the DOM is generally not a great idea but i'm sure you know that

Comment: @roasted Whats the alternative. I want something to keep listening for an event

Comment: @CJ If it's *only* triggered by AJAX calls then you could listen for the `ajaxcomplete` event. There are potential issues with the order of event bindings, but if you call your script after any other external ones it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here, for example the table class is named `table`

```
$('.table > tbody:empty').parent().hide();
```

For checking all the tables:

```
// Call the CheckTables function after 100 milliseconds
setInterval(CheckTables, 100);

function CheckTables()
{
    $( "table " ).each(function( index ) {
      $(this).find('tbody:empty').parent().hide();
      $(this).find('tbody:not(:empty)').parent().show();
    });
}
```

Comment: isnt this class named table?

Comment: That's just a demo 'class'.

Comment: As with PSR's answer, this is **not** a continuous check; it also hides the moment it has no elements, it won't re-show it once some are added. Doesn't address the full requirements of the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.className> tbody:empty').parent().hide();
```

or

```
$('.className tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).remove();
});​
```

Comment: @C J if you got the solution with my answer please accept this as answer

Comment: Considering this quite vital part of the question - "I want something that will **keep checking the table on its own**" - I'm not sure this actually answers it at all.

Comment: Not Working `'<h2>Categories</h2>
<table class="tablesorter table-bordered table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th class="filter-false">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tablesorter > tbody:empty').parent().hide();
</script> `

Comment: $('.tablesorter > tbody:empty').parent().hide();remove \

Comment: i made a mistake while add the comment. Its really not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $('table').each(function(){
      if($('tbody:empty',this))
         $(this).hide();
      else $(this).show();
   });
 });
```